# Reading Files insinde a ,Jar

Tags: java, file, jar, fileinputstream, javax.imageio

I need to retrieve some .png files from an assets file in the project.

I first did `ImageIO.read(new File("assets/img.png"))` but it didn't work once I exported the project to .jar, so I did `ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("assets/img.png"))`, but it still doesn't work in the .jar file...

I finally did `ImageIO.read(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("assets/img.png"))` but it returns a null...

How can I read image files in a folder, inside the .jar? Thanks!

Here is how my project is setup:

```
|Project/
|-com.n1ark.project/
|--Main.java
|--Other classes
|-assets/
|--ing.png
|--Other Images
```

Comment: You might also check to make sure the image is actually being included in the JAR. Quick way to scan JAR contents from command line: `jar -t < example.jar`

Comment: Okay the textures just weren't being packaged with the project. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

the best practice is not put an image inside a jar, you should create a project structure like this:

```
|----- project-folder
|--------- app.jar
|--------- assets
|------------- img.png
|------------- img2.png
```

so in your code you can simly use:

```
ImageIO.read(new File("assets/img.png"));
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with putting images inside JARs.

Comment: I explained myself wrongly, the problem is when I export the project to a jar, my project is actually setup like you're showing!

Comment: notice that in my solution app.jar is what you've exported so you can create a folder called project-folder somewhere in your pc and put inside the jar you've exported and another folder called imgs that contains images and everything will work just fine. I said that this is the best practise bacause you don't need to put a resource file inside a jar and this made the application's packaging easier, never said that put an image inside a jar is wrong @dnault .